# Ratio of decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, $x>0$ positive, smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}_+$. 
Assume that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$, and that both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are strictly decreasing. Further, assume that $f'(x) < g'(x)$ for all $x$, i.e., $f(x)$ is decreasing faster than $g(x)$.

Is it then the case that the ratio

$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $$ 
is a decreasing function of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $g(x) = e^{-2x}$ and $f(x) = 2e^{-x}$.

The reason for this is that for $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to decrease, we must have

$$\frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2} < 0$$

which is if and only if $\frac{f'}{f} < \frac{g'}{g}$ because $f, g$ are positive. Clearly $f' < g'$ is not sufficient since the weights $\frac{1}{f}, \frac{1}{g}$ can change the inequality sign.

In other words, the condition equivalent to the decreasing of $\frac{f}{g}$ is that the *relative* decrease of $f$ must be faster than the *relative* decrease of $g$ and the assumption only ensures the above for the *absolute* decrease of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Hmm.. in your example $g'(x) = f'(x)$?

Comment: $f'(x) = -2e^{-x}$ and $g'(x) = -2e^{-2x}$ so $f'(x) < g'(x)$.

Comment: of course, my mistake! do you know what conditions one would have to place on functions to be relatively decreasing?

Comment: What do you mean by relatively decreasing? By the relative decrease of $f$ in my answer I meant the function $\frac{f'}{f}$, but I haven't defined the notion of a relatively decreasing function.

Comment: what if in addition $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)/g(x) = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

It might be late, but taking upon @Adayah's answer you need to show that

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}<\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

Thinking about $\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)= \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$, we may express the above inequality as

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)<\frac{d}{dx}\log g(x).$$
When $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and since the exponential is strictly increasing and continuous you may pull the exponential into the differential-operator (since it is a limit) which gives

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x)<\frac{d}{dx}g(x).$$ Which establishes your desired property.

Or did i missed out something?